# Import MySQL Query from one server straight to another?

Tags: mysql

I have two Linux (Debian) servers with MySQL (5.5) on them.

How can I run a query on one and import it directly into another one. I was thinking of something like the below, but can't figure out the last bit.

```
mysql -h1.2.3.4 -P3306 -uxxxx -pxxxx -e "SELECT id FROM db1.table1 limit 10" | mysql -h5.6.7.8 -P3306 -uxxxx -pxxxx -e "INSERT INTO db2.table2 (id) VALUES ????"
```

Is this actually possible, or do I need to find some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to generate a db script of your existing DB then execute this on the target destination DB command line. Dont forget to copy the generated sql script into the destination if it is a seperate machine.

```
mysql -u <username> -p <databasename> < <scriptFilname.sql>
```